What is this outdoor electric component called and used for?
This box was previously linked to an outdoor artificial pond filter, as far as I can see.  However, now nothing in the system works.  The outlet next to the unit also doesn't work.
Does anyone know what it was for?  They are buttons of some kind under the soft cover, but they don't seem to do anything when you push them.  I'd like to replace everything myself or call an electrician to do it.



I am guessing it's a weather-sealed switch of sone kind, but not one I've seen and I can't guess the intent. Where do the other wires go?

If the outlet doesn’t work, then presumably this box isn’t getting power either. If you restore power, the buttons may actually do something.

Follow the flex cables and see where they lead.
As you say it was linked (is linked?) to a pond filter, probably it's switching pumps connected to the flex, and perhaps also lights if there are lights - something electrical associated with a pond.
So generally it appears (from your description so far) to be an outdoor switch enclosure, UK flavor judging by the receptacle.
Lack of power to both likely means an RCD or circuit breaker located elsewhere in the building has tripped due to a fault and stopped supplying power to them both.
Minimum fix would be to find that upstream device and attempt to reset it. If it won't reset, the fault (whether to earth or between live and neutral) was not intermittent and you'll have to find and fix where the fault is.
Depending how long it's been sitting idle, you might also need to clean out the pumps for them to start working again.
It's possible that there might be a transformer in the box. It appears to get mains voltage, but it might make that into low voltage for the things attached to the switch buttons. Or it might not. You'd have to look, or find a product that looks just like it from a UK Pond Filter supplier, perhaps. Might have been easier to figure out if the upper label had been more weatherproof than it appears to have been.
